# 'Absolute' position gets moved by elements from list React Native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I want to have a fixed button on the right bottom side of the screen, but it moves depending on the items that are mapped/rendered in the list. If there are a lot of `jobs` then it'll move to the bottom, but if there is only 1 item in `jobs` list then the button will show on top:

```
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={generalStyles.container}> //container only has margin styling (not important)
        {jobs.map((job, i) => (
          <TouchableOpacity style={generalStyles.jobListItem} index={i} key={i} onPress={() => console.log(job + 'got clicked uwu')}>
            <Text style={generalStyles.jobListItemText}>
              {job}
            </Text>
            <IconButton style={generalStyles.jobListItemIcon} icon={props => <MaterialIcon name="add-box" {...props} size={70} />} color={colors[3]} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))
        }
      </View>
      <View> //Button moves depending on how many jobs there are
        <IconButton
          onPress={() => console.log('route to add new job screen')}
          style={generalStyles.homeAddJobButton}
          icon={props => <IonIcon name='add-circle-sharp' {...props} size={100} color={colors[5]} />}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

The stylings are as followed:

```
 jobListItem: {
    backgroundColor: colors[1],
    padding: 30,
    marginVertical: 2,
    borderRadius: 7,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },

  homeAddJobButton: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    borderRadius: 999,
    position:'absolute',
    alignSelf:'flex-end',
    bottom: 50
  },
```

If I comment everything out except the `<IconButton/>` then it's in the correct position, but when I add the other components it starts positioning incorrectly. Anybody know why it doesn't keep its position fixed?

What I tried so far:

```
  <View style={generalStyles.container}> //positions: relative
        {jobs.map((job, i) => (
          <TouchableOpacity style={generalStyles.jobListItem} index={i} key={i} onPress={() => console.log(job + 'got clicked uwu')}>
            <Text style={generalStyles.jobListItemText}>
              {job}
            </Text>
            <IconButton style={generalStyles.jobListItemIcon} icon={props => <MaterialIcon name="add-box" {...props} size={70} />} color={colors[3]} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
 
        <IconButton  //position: absolute, still gets moved by other child element
          onPress={() => console.log('route to add new job screen')}
          style={generalStyles.homeAddJobButton}
          icon={props => <IonIcon name='add-circle-sharp' {...props} size={100} color={colors[5]} />}
        />
      </View>
```

Comment: @rosmak `fixed` doesn't exist in styling in React Native

Answer (score 0):

The absolute positioned element needs to have a parent with position relative. The relative positioning property is what sets that object as the frame of reference for absolute positioned elements.

You can make `body` position relative which will allow your button to stay where you want it. However, if the button has an ancestor with relative positioning that isn't the body, the button will be influenced by that element instead of the body. This is why the button would be moving.

One way to ensure the button stays where you want it is to make it a direct child of the body element. Otherwise you'll need to make sure that none of the button's parents are relatively positioned except for the body.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  /* ... */
}
.your-button {
  position: absolute;
  /* ... */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Your content</div>
  <div class='your-button'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I put the Icon component in the `<View style={generalStyles.container}>`-component, made the parent `relative`, kept the other one absolute. But it still moves.

Comment: It’s always going to move with its closest relatively positioned parent. It will only stay where you want it to if that is the body.

Comment: If you want to make a button with an icon, you make the icon absolute and the button relative. That way the icon always moves with the button. This is similar to the issue you’re having except you want it to stay with the body.

Comment: The thing in your example relative to mine, is that if `<div>Your content</div>` becomes bigger. It moves `<div class='your-button'></div>` even though I made the second `div` absolute and the `body` relative :/